# Wordpress: Deleted comments in DB but still shows count in admin sidebar. How can I fix this?

Tags: wordpress

I noticed a lot of spam posts, comments, & users on my WordPress site.  I directly deleted all of the spam from the database, but I'm still seeing a comment count in the sidebar and on the edit-comments.php page as if I never deleted anything.  I cannot figure out where this  number is coming from and would like to fix it.

WP v5.7.2 with a BeTheme theme.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue.

1. In the WP database, I searched and wanted to delete any pending comments. I did not have any.
2. I cleaned the browser and Wordpress cache.
3. I created a new post and added a comment.
4. I deleted my new comment and then the post.

The number of pending comments went down to zero as I wanted.

This is not the professional way of solving this issue but allowed me to move on.  I'll post if I find a better way to clear this incorrect "pending messages count number".